# Android: Using EndlessScrollListener in listview just keeps on loading data when scrolled up

Tags: java, android, endlessscroll

This is my EndLessScrollListener.java. Does anyone have faced this issue wherein you scroll up and it keeps on scrolling right to the top of the list.I am building a app similar to hangouts for chat messages wherein the latest message is right at the bottom. So to view the older chat messages the user scrolls up and it keeps on scrolling right to the top. Please help. FYI I am using these two attributes in my listView:
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"

```
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;

/*
 * https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews
 */
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
private int currentPage = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;
// Sets the starting page index
private int startingPageIndex = 0;
private boolean reverse = false;

public EndlessScrollListener() {
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, boolean reverse) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    this.reverse = reverse;
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
    this.currentPage = startPage;
}

// This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place        here.
// We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more    data,
// but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int   totalItemCount) {
    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
    }

    // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        currentPage++;
    }

    // If reverse then the firstVisibleItem is calculated wrong
    if (reverse) {
        firstVisibleItem = totalItemCount - firstVisibleItem;
    }
    // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        loading = true;
    }
}

// Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // Don't take any action on changed
}

public void reset() {
    currentPage = 0;
    previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    loading = true;
    startingPageIndex = 0;
}
}

This is my xml file.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sendMessageLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="48dp" >

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/convo_send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessage"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="New message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/g3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#DBDCDC" />
</RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/conversation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sendMessageLayout"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/conversation_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue by using this code

```
    if (view.isStackFromBottom()) {
        if (!loading && firstVisibleItem == 0 ) {
            onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    else if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        loading = true;
    }
```

and when the onLoadMore succeeds with new data I scroll to the previous first item to prevent onScroll from getting called with firstVisibleItem = 0

```
    ListItemObject firstObject = mAdapter.getItem(0);
    mAdapter.addAll(0, resultsObject);

    int index = mAdapter.indexOf(firstObject);
                    // Scroll to the previous first item position to avoid
                    // Calling onLoadMore again
     if (index != -1) {
              mMessagesListView.setSelection(index);
     }
```